# odoo 10 : Hide / show report in menu conditionally

Tags: xml, report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have a custom report which I want to show / hide in menu based on condition....ex. picking_type_id.code in delivery order ...

Can we add any domain filter in this ?

```
    the report menu of module 'custom_reports'

    <report
        string="Picking Operations"
        id="action_report_picking_custom_report"
        model="stock.picking"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="custom_reports.report_picking"
        file="custom_reports.report_picking_operations_custom"
    />
```

how do I achieve this ... ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to simply hide the report from the Print menu and create a button to execute the printing. The button can be hidden based on your conditions.

Comment: I will give a try... Thanks

Comment: This trick can work, but I need to use condition based on fields of relational field  .... which in Odoo 10, I guess, has been stopped ....

Comment: It can be used as a condition of a related field provided that the related field is included on the view. Example: We want to hide the Confirm Order button on the Sales Order if the Customer's Credit Limit is less than the Total Amount. Credit Limit is not a field on the `sale.order` model by default, so we must create a custom field on the `sale.order` model: `fields.Float(related='partner_id.credit_limit` We can then show include the Credit Limit field on the Sales Order form view (invisible or not) to use as a `domain` condition for our button.

Comment: Hello, i have same problem. I use button in print action. I don't understand how to print excel report. Help me.

Comment: @С.Дэлгэрцэцэг Printing a report do Excel is a different topic than using QWeb Reports. You should create a separate question. You might be able to build a pivot view, like the Sales Report, which can save to Excel file. Otherwise, I would suggest searching for some 3rd party modules which generate Excel reports and go based off of those.